# When to use || vs. OR in ColdFusion in a <cfif>?

Tags: syntax, coldfusion, if-statement

When do I use an "OR" vs a || in a ColdFusion cfif statement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Double pipe (as well as double ampersand) are supported in ColdFusion since CF8. Since learning that, I always use double pipe/double ampersand instead of OR/AND. The reason why I code with this style is that "OR" is not completely descriptive with regards to the operation being performed. There's bitwise-OR, logical-OR, and logical-OR with short-circuiting.

Bitwise OR: `01 | 10 = 11`

Logical OR: `buildErrorsOn(form.varA) | buildErrorsOn(form.varB)`

Logical OR (short-circuit): `isDefined('url.doStuff') || isDefined('url.doStuff')`

In just about any language you could use right now (Oracle seeming to be a notable exception), double pipe always means Logical-OR with short-circuiting. It's a precise notation.

Comment: Though I do prefer || and &&, I have to admit it is a lot more likely one would mistake || for | than it is to mistake the long-hand versions OR and BitOr. At least at first ..

Answer (score 6):

I prefer || in CFSCRIPT and OR in CFML.

Answer (score 2):

There may be support in CF9 that brings parity to those keywords, though I couldn't find a reference to indicate that. Really, you are probably better off just using the OR keyword in CFIF, and saving the || for string concatenation in SQL queries.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like || has been supported since CF8.  [CF8 documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Expressions_04.html)

I always find "or" more intuitive.  (For that matter, I always use "+" for string concatenation in SQL - or is that exclusive to SQL Server?)

Comment: Yes, for sql "+" is SQL Server specific. If memory serves, Oracle uses "||" (confusingly ;), MySQL CONCAT(), ...

Comment: One would hope (or wish, at least) there could be agreement at least on a simple logical operator :-/

Comment: Haha.. we can _wish_. But that is about all.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about this, but it would appear that a `cfif` statement only supports OR, so the answer to your question is 'always'. See this:

- http://coldfusion.sys-con.com/node/44479